# flickr plugin for CKEditor / CKFinder

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, flickr, ckfinder

I've done a google search and can't seem to find one anyone know if one exists or not ?

Hopefully it would allow the user to select a photo from flicker to put into the ckeditor area with the correct url .. and for bonus it would be cool if they could browse for an image that would get posted to flicker and be put in editor with the correct url as well

**more info**
there seem to be a number of flickr plugins that do what I want in wordpress but not for the ckeditor or ckfinder I wonder if anyone knows how I could use one of the wordpress plugins outside of wordpress ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I only know Wordpress plugins like [Wordpress Flickr Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-flickr-manager/). Reading it's source code you could understand how it works and implement your own. I've used this plugin in the past, and does exactly what you want, a flickr's photo in the editor with the correct url.

Begin with `FlickrManager.php`, `function manage_page()`, `default` value in `switch`, this is where the plugin shows a panel to add an image to a post: it creates a shortcode value in your post, so remember to check `function image_shortcode()` in the same module as well.